# How to use main variable in functions?

Tags: c++

I got a function but i can't define any variable inside and global too. This function gets a char value from user. I need to define this value to main function. How can i do it? Thanks for helping guys.

This is my code. I made it like this but I define variables in global but I need to define this variables in only main.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char cName[255], cSurname[255];

bool nameFunc() {

    cout << "Whats Your Name ?\n";
    cin >> cName;
    if (cName != NULL && cName[0] == '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool surnameFunc() {
    cout << "Whats Your Surname ?\n";
    cin >> cSurname;
    if (cSurname != NULL && cSurname[0] == '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    if (nameFunc() and surnameFunc()) {
        cout << "Hello, " << cName << " " << cSurname << "." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error! Name or Surname is empty." << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the [tour] of stackoverflow.com, reading the [help], and learning [ask] questions here. Now, having done all that, what would be your question, again?

Comment: I don't think the sarcasm's helpful, @Sam.

Comment: Please show a [mre] with the code you've tried and any compiler error you receive

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `std::string`?

Comment: This is for my school work. Teacher did't teach std::string to us, Thats why he doesn't want to use.

Comment: @eally-root Ok, note that doing `cin >>` into a `char*` uses [`operator>>` - overload 2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) and it looks like it'll be changed in C++20 just because it's unsafe and using it has caused a lot of real problems - so don't. Ask your teacher for a safe alternative. (The new C++20 overload takes a reference to an array instead and is therefore safe to use)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Its ok. Thank you for informing me.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool nameFunc(char* cName) {

    cout << "Whats Your Name ?\n";
    cin >> cName;
    if (cName != NULL && cName[0] == '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

bool surnameFunc(char* cSurname) {
    cout << "Whats Your Surname ?\n";
    cin >> cSurname;
    if (cSurname != NULL && cSurname[0] == '\0') {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

int main() {
    char cName[255], cSurname[255];
    if (nameFunc(cName) and surnameFunc(cSurname)) {
        cout << "Hello, " << cName << " " << cSurname << "." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Error! Name or Surname is empty." << endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >>` to a `char*` is a really bad idea. It has no way of knowing where the array ends so it can write out-of-bounds. Don't do this even if it looks like it solves your problem right now.

Comment: Even worse, your code is checking for non-null pointers AFTER writing to those pointers as a string.   At that point, the damage is done - if the pointer is `NULL`, then streaming to it from `cin` has undefined behaviour, so there is no point in checking it afterward.   There is a reason that C++ provides library types like `std::string` which avoid this sort of terrible technique.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I was just answering the question, I did not try to re-arrange the code, of course all your points are valid and your solution way better

Comment: @PhM75 In C++20 the overload for `operator>>` actually looks like something like this: `istream& operator>>(istream& st, char (&s)[N] );`. I'm not sure if the overload for taking a `char*` will still be valid (for the reasons mentioned) but by introducing a `char*` when OP used a `char[255]` is making it worse than the original code (in C++20 that is). In C++17, OP:s code and your code are equally unsafe.

Answer (score 4):

You could pass references to your variables to the functions. Since the `char[]` have a fixed length, you need to make sure that you don't write out-of-bounds which complicates things.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
bool nameFunc(char (&cName)[N]) {
    std::cout << "Whats Your Name ?\n";
    std::cin.getline(cName, N);            // read at most N chars
    return cName[0] != '\0';
}

template<size_t N>
bool surnameFunc(char (&cSurname)[N]) {
    std::cout << "Whats Your Surname ?\n";
    std::cin.getline(cSurname, N);         // read at most N chars
    return cSurname[0] != '\0';
}

int main() {
    char cName[255], cSurname[255];

    if (nameFunc(cName) and surnameFunc(cSurname)) {
        std::cout << "Hello, " << cName << " " << cSurname << ".\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Error! Name or Surname is empty.\n";
    }
}
```

A much easier option would be to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)s and pass them by reference to the functions.